# xp_cmdshel Проблема с кодировкой при печати

Tags: sql, кодировка

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(255)='D:\MSSQL\Printcon\'
DECLARE @pn NVARCHAR(255), @rn NVARCHAR(255), @f NVARCHAR(512)
SELECT @pn='"'+ connection + '"'FROM printer WHERE id=@PrinterId
SELECT @rn='"'+ [file] + '"'FROM report  WHERE id=@ReportId
SET @f='cmd.exe /c  '+@path+'printcon.exe ' + @rn + ' ' + @pn + ' "'+ REPLACE(@params,';','" "') + '" '
PRINT @f
EXEC xp_cmdshell @f, no_output
```

В бд существует процедура печати, но проблемы с кодировакой. Если руками выполнить что формирует процедура, то все ок. Из студии кракозябры

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения кодировки так же применим chcp в следующем формате:

Chcp <код>

Где <код> – это цифровой параметр нужного шрифта, например,

```
1251 – Windows (кириллица);

866 – DOC-кодировка;

65001 – UTF-8;
```

Выбирайте на любой вкус. Т.о. что бы изменить кодировку на UTF-8 нужно выполнить команду chcp 65001.